# selecting one specific column out of a text file

Tags: python, csv

I want to select just the second column of the below text file which is: 500, 1000, 1500, ..., 4500, 5000, 5500, ... , 21000

I have attached a picture of my text file below.

I have used the script below to do that, but I don't have the number 500 in my result:

```
with open("example", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter =" ")
    second_column = list(zip(*reader))[3]
```

Can someone help me out with how to fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `read_csv` function from the `pandas` library. For instance:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", delimiter=",")
```

Select the right `delimiter`. What you will get is a `pandas` `DataFrame`. Then you can select your column of interest by using, for instance, the column header:

```
my_column = data["my_column"]
```

If you prefer working with numpy, you can convert the `my_column` series to a numpy array by using the `to_numpy()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Second column - index=1. In your code the index is 3. Must be 1.

```
with open("example", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter =" ")
    second_column = list(zip(*reader))[1]
```

Comment: not the case of a single space as a delimiter

Answer (score 0):

The example you show is not a csv-file. From the perspective of a space-delimited data the first cell is placed at the 4th position, not 3rd.

As a workaround, we can try `pandas.read_csv(your_data, sep='\s+', engine='python')`. But first I would try something more basic - read, filter, split and take data at index 1:

```
with open("example", "r") as f:
    second_column = [int(line.split()[1]) for line in f if not line.startswith('#')]
```

Note, that `str.split` will use a space as a delimiter by default and drop any empty strings from the result, which is similar to `sep='\s+'` in the pandas csv-reader.
Also some `line.strip().startswith('#')` would be appropriate in a more general case.